# Start telebot_proxy in python and Connection error

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I got an error when trying to connect to Telegram and Python with the following proxy

### Code

```py
import os
import requests
import socket
import socks
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper
from telebot import types
import urllib3
   
TOKEN = "87-----------------------ewCp10yzTJhQ"
ip='192.111.139.165' #your proxy's ip
port = 4145 #your proxy's port
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, ip, port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket 
    
url = 'http://ip.42.pl/raw'
print(requests.get(url).text)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
url = 'http://ip.42.pl/raw'
print(requests.get(url).text)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def botmain(user):
    usertext = user.text
    userchatid = user.chat.id
    ipp = "http://ip.42.pl/raw"
    print(usertext)
    print(str(ipp))
    print(requests.get(ipp).text)


bot.polling(True)
```

*Note*: The proxy is now safe and has been checked

### Error Message

```py
C:\Users\rashi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot87--70:AAGv------------------wCp10yzTJhQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ``'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

Can someone help me identify the where the connection is? Also, what is the reason for not connecting to the proxy? (Maybe the location of my code is wrong, but I am not sure.)